# Snakemake checkpoint output unknown number of files with no subsequent aggregation but instead rules that peform actions on individual files?

Tags: snakemake

Thanks for any help ahead of time.

I'm trying to use the Snakemake checkpoint functionality to produce an unknown number of files in a directory, which I've gotten to work using the pattern described in the docs, but then I **don't** want to do any kind of aggregation rule afterwards, I want to have rules that do actions on each individual file (of course inherently in parallel via wildcards).

Here's a simple reproducible example of my problem:

```py
from os.path import join


rule all:
    input:
        "aggregated.txt",


checkpoint create_gzip_file:
    output:
        directory("my_directory/"),
    shell:
        """
        mkdir my_directory/
        cd my_directory
        for i in 1 2 3; do gzip < /dev/null > $i.txt.gz; done
        """


rule gunzip_file:
    input:
        join("my_directory", "{i}.txt.gz"),
    output:
        join("my_directory", "{i}.txt"),
    shell:
        """
        gunzip -c {input} > {output}
        """


def gather_gunzip_input(wildcards):
    out_dir = checkpoints.create_gzip_file.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    i = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz"))
    return expand(f"{out_dir}/{{i}}", i=i)


rule aggregate:
    input:
        gather_gunzip_input,
    output:
        "aggregated.txt",
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```bash
$ snakemake --printshellcmds --cores all
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 16
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job                 count    min threads    max threads
----------------  -------  -------------  -------------
aggregate               1              1              1
all                     1              1              1
create_gzip_file        1              1              1
total                   3              1              1

Select jobs to execute...

[Wed Jul 13 14:57:09 2022]
checkpoint create_gzip_file:
    output: my_directory
    jobid: 2
    reason: Missing output files: my_directory
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp
Downstream jobs will be updated after completion.


        mkdir my_directory/
        cd my_directory
        for i in 1 2 3; do gzip < /dev/null > $i.txt.gz; done
        
[Wed Jul 13 14:57:09 2022]
Finished job 2.
1 of 3 steps (33%) done
MissingInputException in line 20 of /home/hermidalc/projects/github/hermidalc/test/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule gunzip_file:
    output: my_directory/['1', '2', '3'].txt
    wildcards: i=['1', '2', '3']
    affected files:
        my_directory/['1', '2', '3'].txt.gz
```

Comment: It would help to provide a reproducible example that gives the error or the unexpected behavior you get. For example, give actual values for strings like `NCBI_ASSEMBLY_GZ_METADATA_FILE` that we can use - it's not easy to debug other people's code just by looking at it and guessing what is what!

Comment: Assume `NCBI_ASSEMBLY_METADATA_FILE` is a TSV file with a bunch of file URLs that get downloaded into `NCBI_ASSEMBLY_DIR`. Sorry thought that was obvious.

It would have download URLs for file names that look like this and end up in `NCBI_ASSEMBLY_DIR`: `GCA_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
GCA_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_genomic.fna.gz
GCA_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_genomic.gff.gz
GCA_000001635.8_GRCm38.p6_cds_from_genomic.fna.gz
GCA_000001635.8_GRCm38.p6_genomic.fna.gz
GCA_000001635.8_GRCm38.p6_genomic.gff.gz
`

Comment: `MissingInputException in line 292 of /home/hermidalc/projects/github/hermidalc/test/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule finished:
    output: data/finished
    affected files:/GCA_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_genomic.fna
        data/genomes/assemblies/GCA_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_cds_from_genomic.fna
        data/genomes/assemblies/GCA_000001215.4_Release_6_plus_ISO1_MT_genomic.gff
`

Comment: How do I do multi-line code in comments? The triple back-ticks don't see to work

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments - the point is not so much clarifying what could be obvious (and maybe it is not so obvious...) but rather enabling us to reproduce your problem just by copying and pasting the code in your question.

Comment: @dariober I updated it now to create a simple reproducible example of the problem

Comment: Ok so I just figured out what is causing the simple example not to work instead of `i = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz"))` I needed to put `i = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz")).i`. So now need to figure out what is going wrong with my actual code, which is the same design as the simple example.

Comment: *I just figured out what is causing the simple example not to work* it's amazing how often you solve your own problems while compiling a simple example!

Comment: It's something you can only find in the snakemake FAQ, but if you `glob_wildcards` with only one wildcard you do it in the style I did you need a trailing comma, i.e. `i, = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz"))`. I know it's more of a python tuple syntax thing than snakemake, but one little comma and then the error sends you on a wild goose chase

Comment: @dariober but to answer the other part of the question, in order to avoid an aggregation rule, I believe I would need to then put the function that gathers the files in the input list of `rule all`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a syntax issue (which wasn't triggering any syntax check or compiler issues) that was causing the seemingly unrelated `MissingInputException`. The `glob_wildcards` line:

```py
i = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz"))
```

needs to be with a trailing comma:

```py
i, = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz"))
```

or

```py
i = glob_wildcards(join(out_dir, "{i}.txt.gz")).i
```

Also, in answering the other part of the question - I believe if you don't want an aggregation-type rule (which uses the function that gathers the unknown number of files as its input) then you need to put that function as input to your `rule all`. As shown in this question, you can continue to have downstream rules of your checkpoint, which do not aggregate, but perform actions on the individual unknown files, you just have to use the wildcards created in your gather function and write the `expand` in the right way that it outputs the file structure for how the output of the last rule performing actions on files from the checkpoint come out.